# closure property on Recursively enumerable language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

How to prove that **recursive and recursively enumerable language** is closed under **reversal**?

Why **recursively enumerable language** is not closed under **set difference**? [But intersection of recursive and recursively enumerable language is recursively enumerable]

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: I want know details about closure property of RE and Recursive language. In most of the books only union, intersection, concatenation, complement and kleene closure are discussed but what for reversal, homomorphism, inverse homomorphism, set difference and substitution. Just mentioned in table. But no proof. Even the set difference of RE is confusing with intersection of recursive and RE language.